# Tableau Action URL: field name needed twice to construct a valid link

Tags: tableau-api

I've used worksheet URL actions in tableau before and they are Great!   But I have a case where to construct a valid link-  I need the field twice.
something like....

"http://wwwin-esstools-prd.cisco.com/pmt/emailfilters/EmailFilter.json/?&id=FIELD&queryObj={"conjunction":"and","expressions":[{"op":"equals","attr":"id","value":FIELD}],"preFilterQuery":"","name":"Advanced Filter"}"

where FIELD  is the field name I would like to use to properly construct the url.  I have tried using both the select and menu options-
both seem to be ignored by tableau.

Answer (score 0):

FIELD needs to be surrounded by angle brackets. You can use the Insert menu on the URL action dialog panel to insert field names into your URL if you prefer, and thus avoid spelling errors. Or simply type the field name and brackets where you want them.